How to find out which graph is most similar to another graph?
I have this list of matrices in R:
 my_list =  structure(list(
        matrix(c(2,2,2,2,3, 1,2,2,2,3, 1,2,3,3,3, 1,2,1,3,3, 1,1,1,3,3), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2, 1,1,1,2,2, 1,1,1,3,3, 1,1,3,3,3, 1,1,3,3,3), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(2,2,2,3,3, 2,2,2,3,3, 1,1,3,3,3, 1,1,3,3,3, 1,1,1,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(3,3,3,3,3, 2,2,3,3,3, 2,2,2,3,3, 2,2,2,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(3,3,3,3,3, 1,1,1,2,2, 1,1,1,2,2, 1,1,1,2,2, 1,1,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(1,1,1,3,3, 1,1,1,3,3, 1,1,1,2,2, 1,1,2,2,2, 1,1,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(1,3,3,2,2, 1,3,3,2,2, 1,1,3,3,2, 1,1,1,3,2, 1,1,1,1,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2, 1,1,1,2,2, 1,1,1,2,3, 1,1,1,2,3, 1,1,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3, 3,3,3,3,3, 1,1,3,3,3, 1,1,3,3,3), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,2, 3,1,1,1,2, 3,3,2,2,2, 3,3,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(3,1,1,1,1, 3,3,1,1,1, 3,3,2,2,1, 2,2,2,1,1, 2,2,2,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(3,3,3,3,3, 3,3,1,3,1, 2,2,1,1,1, 2,2,1,1,1, 2,2,1,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(3,3,1,1,1, 3,1,1,1,1, 3,2,2,1,1, 3,2,2,2,2, 3,3,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,2, 1,1,1,1,2, 3,3,3,2,2, 3,3,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(1,1,1,1,2, 1,1,1,3,2, 1,3,1,3,2, 1,3,3,3,2, 1,1,3,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(3,3,3,3,3, 3,3,2,2,2, 3,3,2,2,2, 1,1,2,2,2, 1,1,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(1,1,1,3,3, 1,1,1,3,3, 1,1,2,2,3, 1,1,1,2,3, 1,1,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(1,1,1,1,3, 1,1,2,3,3, 1,1,2,3,3, 1,1,2,2,2, 1,2,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1, 1,2,2,1,1, 1,1,2,2,1, 3,3,2,2,2, 2,2,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(3,3,3,1,1, 1,1,1,1,2, 1,1,1,1,2, 1,2,1,2,2, 1,2,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(2,3,3,3,3, 2,3,3,3,3, 2,3,3,3,3, 2,2,2,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(2,2,2,2,2, 2,2,2,2,2, 2,2,2,2,2, 2,3,1,1,2, 3,3,1,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1, 3,1,1,1,1, 2,2,1,1,1, 2,2,1,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(1,1,1,3,3, 2,1,1,3,3, 2,2,1,1,3, 2,2,2,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1, 3,3,3,3,1, 2,2,2,2,1, 2,2,2,2,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(3,3,3,3,1, 3,3,2,1,1, 3,3,2,1,1, 3,3,2,2,2, 3,3,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(3,3,3,1,1, 3,3,3,1,1, 3,2,2,1,1, 2,2,2,1,1, 2,2,2,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(2,2,2,1,1, 2,2,2,1,1, 2,2,1,1,1, 3,2,2,1,1, 3,3,1,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1, 1,2,1,1,1, 1,2,2,1,1, 1,1,2,3,3, 1,1,2,3,3), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(1,1,3,3,3, 1,2,2,2,3, 1,2,2,3,3, 1,2,2,3,3, 1,1,1,3,3), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(3,1,1,1,1, 3,1,1,1,1, 3,3,1,1,2, 3,1,1,2,2, 3,2,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(1,1,1,3,3, 1,1,1,3,3, 2,3,3,3,3, 2,3,3,2,2, 2,2,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(3,2,2,2,2, 3,2,2,2,2, 3,1,2,1,1, 3,1,1,1,1, 3,3,3,3,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(3,3,3,3,3, 3,3,3,1,1, 2,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2, 2,2,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(3,3,3,3,2, 3,3,3,3,2, 3,1,1,1,2, 3,1,1,1,1, 3,1,1,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
        matrix(c(3,3,2,2,2, 3,1,1,2,2, 3,1,1,2,2, 1,1,1,2,2, 1,1,1,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE)
    ), class = "list")

I then plotted all of them using the following code:
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

plot_matrix <- function(mat, plot_number) {
    df <- melt(mat)
    names(df) <- c("row", "col", "value")
    
    df$index <- (df$row - 1) * 5 + df$col
    
    colors <- c(
        "1" = "#FFB3B3",
        "2" = "#B3D9FF",
        "3" = "#B3FFB3"
    )
    
    p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = col, y = -row, fill = factor(value))) +
        geom_tile(color = "black", linewidth = 0.5) +
        geom_text(aes(label = index), size = 3) +
        scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
        labs(title = paste("Object", plot_number)) +
        coord_equal() +
        theme_minimal() +
        theme(
            legend.position = "none",
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(b = 10)),
            axis.text = element_blank(),
            axis.title = element_blank(),
            panel.grid = element_blank(),
            plot.margin = margin(5, 5, 5, 5)
        )
    
    return(p)
}

plot_list <- lapply(seq_along(my_list), function(i) {
    plot_matrix(my_list[[i]], i)
})

n_plots <- length(plot_list)
n_cols <- 6
n_rows <- ceiling(n_plots / n_cols)

grid.arrange(
    grobs = plot_list,
    ncol = n_cols,
    nrow = n_rows,
    padding = unit(2, "mm")
)


I have the following question: If we take object 1 - is there something we can do to find out which of the remaining objects is "most similar" to object 1 based on : A) distribution of colors AND B) shape of color boundaries AND C) placement of color boundaries?
My current approach is to answer each one of these questions separately and average them. For example:

A) Find out the color distribution of each object as a vector and take the euclidean distance between object 1 and all other objects.

B) and C) Use something like Jaccard Distance or Hausdorf Distance between object 1 and all other objects

take the average of all differences to get an idea of general similarity. The pair (object1, object_i) with the lowest average is most similar


I am not sure how correct this approach is and I was wondering if there is something easier.

An idea for A)
library(plotly)

color_counts <- data.frame(
    object = 1:length(my_list),
    red = sapply(my_list, function(mat) sum(mat == 1)),
    blue = sapply(my_list, function(mat) sum(mat == 2)),
    green = sapply(my_list, function(mat) sum(mat == 3))
)

point_colors <- ifelse(color_counts$object == 1, "orange", "black")

plot_ly(color_counts, 
        x = ~red, 
        y = ~blue, 
        z = ~green,
        text = ~paste("Object", object),
        type = "scatter3d",
        mode = "markers",
        marker = list(
            color = point_colors,
            size = 6  # Making points slightly larger for better visibility
        )) %>%
    layout(scene = list(
        xaxis = list(title = "Red (1s)"),
        yaxis = list(title = "Blue (2s)"),
        zaxis = list(title = "Green (3s)")
    ))



This type of question is not well-suited to stackoverflow. It's not really about programming / software development (I didn't downvote you but I suspect this is why you've been downvoted) and it's difficult to evaluate solutions, i.e. what's the answer? Which Object is 'closest' to Object 1? Which is closest to Object 2? Without having your expected output it's hard to develop potential solutions.

This question is hard to answer, but Part A and Part B should be relatively straightforward, hclust() and a some sort of jaccard distance can be calculated (although not the traditional jaccard 'how many things in common', as all Objects have the same values (1, 2, and 3) but in they're in different positions).
The part that I'm struggling with is:

B) shape of color boundaries AND C) placement of color boundaries?

This is way outside my area of expertise, but perhaps the clustering-type approaches might help you get started.
E.g.
library(tidyverse)
my_list =  structure(list(
  matrix(c(2,2,2,2,3, 1,2,2,2,3, 1,2,3,3,3, 1,2,1,3,3, 1,1,1,3,3), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2, 1,1,1,2,2, 1,1,1,3,3, 1,1,3,3,3, 1,1,3,3,3), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(2,2,2,3,3, 2,2,2,3,3, 1,1,3,3,3, 1,1,3,3,3, 1,1,1,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(3,3,3,3,3, 2,2,3,3,3, 2,2,2,3,3, 2,2,2,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(3,3,3,3,3, 1,1,1,2,2, 1,1,1,2,2, 1,1,1,2,2, 1,1,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(1,1,1,3,3, 1,1,1,3,3, 1,1,1,2,2, 1,1,2,2,2, 1,1,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(1,3,3,2,2, 1,3,3,2,2, 1,1,3,3,2, 1,1,1,3,2, 1,1,1,1,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2, 1,1,1,2,2, 1,1,1,2,3, 1,1,1,2,3, 1,1,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3, 3,3,3,3,3, 1,1,3,3,3, 1,1,3,3,3), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,2, 3,1,1,1,2, 3,3,2,2,2, 3,3,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(3,1,1,1,1, 3,3,1,1,1, 3,3,2,2,1, 2,2,2,1,1, 2,2,2,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(3,3,3,3,3, 3,3,1,3,1, 2,2,1,1,1, 2,2,1,1,1, 2,2,1,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(3,3,1,1,1, 3,1,1,1,1, 3,2,2,1,1, 3,2,2,2,2, 3,3,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,2, 1,1,1,1,2, 3,3,3,2,2, 3,3,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(1,1,1,1,2, 1,1,1,3,2, 1,3,1,3,2, 1,3,3,3,2, 1,1,3,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(3,3,3,3,3, 3,3,2,2,2, 3,3,2,2,2, 1,1,2,2,2, 1,1,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(1,1,1,3,3, 1,1,1,3,3, 1,1,2,2,3, 1,1,1,2,3, 1,1,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(1,1,1,1,3, 1,1,2,3,3, 1,1,2,3,3, 1,1,2,2,2, 1,2,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1, 1,2,2,1,1, 1,1,2,2,1, 3,3,2,2,2, 2,2,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(3,3,3,1,1, 1,1,1,1,2, 1,1,1,1,2, 1,2,1,2,2, 1,2,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(2,3,3,3,3, 2,3,3,3,3, 2,3,3,3,3, 2,2,2,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(2,2,2,2,2, 2,2,2,2,2, 2,2,2,2,2, 2,3,1,1,2, 3,3,1,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1, 3,1,1,1,1, 2,2,1,1,1, 2,2,1,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(1,1,1,3,3, 2,1,1,3,3, 2,2,1,1,3, 2,2,2,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1, 3,3,3,3,1, 2,2,2,2,1, 2,2,2,2,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(3,3,3,3,1, 3,3,2,1,1, 3,3,2,1,1, 3,3,2,2,2, 3,3,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(3,3,3,1,1, 3,3,3,1,1, 3,2,2,1,1, 2,2,2,1,1, 2,2,2,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(2,2,2,1,1, 2,2,2,1,1, 2,2,1,1,1, 3,2,2,1,1, 3,3,1,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1, 1,2,1,1,1, 1,2,2,1,1, 1,1,2,3,3, 1,1,2,3,3), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(1,1,3,3,3, 1,2,2,2,3, 1,2,2,3,3, 1,2,2,3,3, 1,1,1,3,3), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(3,1,1,1,1, 3,1,1,1,1, 3,3,1,1,2, 3,1,1,2,2, 3,2,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(1,1,1,3,3, 1,1,1,3,3, 2,3,3,3,3, 2,3,3,2,2, 2,2,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(3,2,2,2,2, 3,2,2,2,2, 3,1,2,1,1, 3,1,1,1,1, 3,3,3,3,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(3,3,3,3,3, 3,3,3,1,1, 2,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2, 2,2,2,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(3,3,3,3,2, 3,3,3,3,2, 3,1,1,1,2, 3,1,1,1,1, 3,1,1,1,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE),
  matrix(c(3,3,2,2,2, 3,1,1,2,2, 3,1,1,2,2, 1,1,1,2,2, 1,1,1,2,2), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE)
), class = "list")

library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'gridExtra'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     combine
library(reshape2)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'reshape2'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     smiths
library(dplyr)

plot_matrix <- function(mat, plot_number) {
  df <- melt(mat)
  names(df) <- c("row", "col", "value")
  
  df$index <- (df$row - 1) * 5 + df$col
  
  colors <- c(
    "1" = "#FFB3B3",
    "2" = "#B3D9FF",
    "3" = "#B3FFB3"
  )
  
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = col, y = -row, fill = factor(value))) +
    geom_tile(color = "black", linewidth = 0.5) +
    geom_text(aes(label = index), size = 3) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
    labs(title = paste("Object", plot_number)) +
    coord_equal() +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
      legend.position = "none",
      plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(b = 10)),
      axis.text = element_blank(),
      axis.title = element_blank(),
      panel.grid = element_blank(),
      plot.margin = margin(5, 5, 5, 5)
    )
  
  return(p)
}

plot_list <- lapply(seq_along(my_list), function(i) {
  plot_matrix(my_list[[i]], i)
})

n_plots <- length(plot_list)
n_cols <- 6
n_rows <- ceiling(n_plots / n_cols)

grid.arrange(
  grobs = plot_list,
  ncol = n_cols,
  nrow = n_rows,
  padding = unit(2, "mm")
)


my_list
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    2    2    2    2    3
#> [2,]    1    2    2    2    3
#> [3,]    1    2    3    3    3
#> [4,]    1    2    1    3    3
#> [5,]    1    1    1    3    3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    1    1    1    2    2
#> [2,]    1    1    1    2    2
#> [3,]    1    1    1    3    3
#> [4,]    1    1    3    3    3
#> [5,]    1    1    3    3    3
#> 
#> ...
#> 
#> [[36]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    3    3    2    2    2
#> [2,]    3    1    1    2    2
#> [3,]    3    1    1    2    2
#> [4,]    1    1    1    2    2
#> [5,]    1    1    1    2    2
#> 
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "list"

# combine all of the melted matrices into a single dataframe
list_of_dfs <- map(seq_along(my_list), ~melt(my_list[[.x]]) %>%
                     mutate(id = .x) %>%
                     pivot_wider(id_cols = id,
                                 names_from = c(Var1, Var2),
                                 values_from = value)) %>%
  bind_rows()

# get all of the combinations, e.g. Object 1 vs 1, 1 vs 2, etc
combinations <- expand.grid(1:nrow(list_of_dfs), 1:nrow(list_of_dfs)) %>%
  filter(Var1 != Var2)
output <- map2(combinations$Var2, combinations$Var1, ~sum(list_of_dfs[.x,] == list_of_dfs[.y,]))
combinations$total_matches <- unlist(output)

# check the top matches i.e. how many values are in the same place
head(combinations[order(combinations$total_matches, decreasing = TRUE),], 15)
#>     Var1 Var2 total_matches
#> 328   14   10            23
#> 465   10   14            23
#> 125   21    4            21
#> 191   17    6            21
#> 566    6   17            21
#> 704    4   21            21
#> 261   17    8            20
#> 376   27   11            20
#> 568    8   17            20
#> 921   11   27            20
#> 29    30    1            19
#> 42     8    2            19
#> 145    6    5            19
#> 159   20    5            19
#> 175   36    5            19

Looks like Object 30 is the closest match to Object 1 (i.e. it has 19 values in the same position in the matrices). Using hclust you get the same answer:

list_of_dfs <- map(seq_along(my_list), ~melt(my_list[[.x]]) %>%
                     mutate(id = .x) %>%
                     pivot_wider(id_cols = id,
                                 names_from = c(Var1, Var2),
                                 values_from = value)) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(across(-id, ~scale(.x)))

hc <- hclust(dist(list_of_dfs[-1]), method = "complete")
plot(hc)


Created on 2024-12-16 with reprex v2.1.0
Hope this helps; good luck!
